# defining a key function in awesome window manager

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, touchpad, context-menu, awesome-wm

I want to reprogramme a key on my laptop-keyboard in awesome window manager under Fedora.
On my new Lenovo's keyboard there is no context-menu-key anymore, but I miss it. Especially in awesome it would come in handy.
So my question is, how can I programme the key with the function of the pop-up context-menu as it is defined for the right click of the mouse/touchpad?
With `xev` I tracked the key, it's called "Print".
So what name has the right-click context-menu function and how do I assign this to the "Print"-key? 
`xev` named it "button 3" but my improvised code `awful.key({ "Print" }), function() button 3 end),` returned an error.

Have some of you a better idea?

Comment: I figured out myself, that the code to programme the "Print"-key must be `awful.key({ }, "Print", function () ... end),` but I have no idea what name the context-menu function of the right mouse button has, because `mymenu:toggle()` simply is the "main menu" of awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured it out completely on my own.

I just followed this guide from [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234416/how-to-remap-the-context-menu-to-another-key-in-linux)

worked perfectly for my problem.

thanks anyway.